# MySQL - Select number of occurrences of values from another table (including zeros)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- First table (*names*) contains different names, all names are included only once.
- Second table (*people*) contains records of some people. All the names (*person* column) in this table are included in the *name* column of the first table.

***names:***

```
id    name
---   -----
1     Linda
2     John
3     Mary
4     Charles
```

***people:***

```
id    person
---   -----
1     John
2     Mary
3     Mary
4     Charles
5     Charles
6     Charles
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acaf4

I want to list the number of occurrences of name values (including zeros) in people table.

I used following query, but the result doesn't contain zero values:

```
SELECT person AS n,
   COUNT(person) AS name_occurrence
FROM people
LEFT JOIN names ON people.person = names.name
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY name_occurrence ASC;
```

The result is:

```
n         name_occurrence
-------   ---------------
John      1
Mary      2
Charles   3
```

What I want is:

```
n         name_occurrence
-------   ---------------
Linda     0
John      1
Mary      2
Charles   3
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76c163/12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `names` table contains all known names, I think that you want to `LEFT JOIN` this table to a table containing the counts of each name as it appears in the `people` table.  In the event that a name does not appear in `people`, I use `COALESCE` to replace that missing count with zero.

```
SELECT n.name,
       COALESCE(t.personCount, 0) AS personCount
FROM names n
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT person, COUNT(*) AS personCount
    FROM people
    GROUP BY person
) t
    ON n.name = t.person
```

Click the link below for a delightful Fiddle using the good work done by @strawberry :

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the join other way around, if you want the first table to be your master record. So you can change the join from left to right